# Can ljust be used within an each block?

Tags: ruby, string, each

```
"test".ljust(5)
=> "test "

["test", "test", "test"].each { |i| i.ljust(5) }
=> ["test", "test", "test"]
```

`ljust` doesn't seem to be working when used within an `each` block. Why in the world isn't this working as expected? Am I missing something? If so, what makes this kind of method behave in such a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to rewrite these, you need to use `map`:

```
["test", "test", "test"].map { |i| i.ljust(5) }
```

The `each` method iterates and *ignores the result*, returning the original list, whereas `map` returns the transformed results.

Note you can do formatting like this with things like:

```
'%-5s' % [ item ]
```

That largely avoids the need to mangle your data just for presentation purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The return of each is the original array. I think what you are looking for is:

```
["test", "test", "test"].map { |i| i.ljust(5) }
```